# Copy CSV to Vertica

Tags: csv, vertica

I have a csv file with headers
col1, col2, col3

I also have table in Vertica 
v_col1, v_col2, v_col3

How I can copy and mapping the data from CSV file into my table (mean col1 -> v_col1 , col2 -> v_col2 etc...)

Thanks

Comment: header name doesn't matter while loading, just check the order of the columns are same in the csv and the table.

Answer (score 0):

The COPY command in Vertica will map the CSV columns to the table by itself.

Suppose the csv file /tmp/t1.csv looks like below:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,100,a
2,200,b
3,300,c
```

Then you can create a table in Vertica and use COPY with DELIMITER ',':

```
=> create table table1(v_col1 int, v_col2 int, v_col3 varchar);
CREATE TABLE
=> copy table1 from '/tmp/t1.csv' delimiter ',';
 Rows Loaded
-------------
           3
=> select * from table1;
 v_col1 | v_col2 | v_col3
--------+--------+--------
      1 |    100 | a
      2 |    200 | b
      3 |    300 | c
(3 rows)
```

Please refer to below document for more COPY examples:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPYExamples.htm

(Edit to the comments)
I don't have an answer to the "mapping" requirement, but I think there is a workaround to achieve that.

After the csv file was copied into a table with the same number of columns, you can create a new table by selecting those columns you want.

For example, you can create a new table (named as table2) which only has the first 2 columns from table1:

```
=> create table table2 as select v_col1,v_col2 from table1;
CREATE TABLE
=> select * from table2;
 v_col1 | v_col2
--------+--------
      2 |    200
      1 |    100
      3 |    300
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks
I'm looking for another solution.
i have Vertica table with 4 columns col1,col2,col3,col4 and difference types:
my csv contains 10 columns (eg csv1...csc10)
i would like to be able to map only 4 columns from the csv
I found the following solution but it's not work if i miss csv columns
copy public.datacsv (
 v1 filler int ,
 v2 filler int ,
 v3 filler int ,   
 v4 filler int , 
 col1 as v2 ,
 col2 as v3 ,
 col3 as v4 ,
 col4 as v1  
  )
 from  '/data/csv/data.csv' delimiter ',' direct ;

in addition, can I drop the type after filler and let Vertica do the work?
Thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer to your "mapping" requirement, but I think there is a workaround to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
copy {vertica_table_name}
from local '{path}'
delimiter ','
enclosed by '"';
```

e.g.

```sql
copy test_table
from local 'D:\test\test.csv'
delimiter ','
enclosed by '"';
```